# Dealing with escape character in python pexpect

Tags: python-3.x, sed, pexpect

Removing backslash from the python strings which uses pexpect is causing some issues. Currently, I'm trying to change a value of json-formatted data.

`'sed -i \'s/pop.*/pop": "1.1.1.100",/\' /root/temp.json'`

The issue is the backslash after -i. This is failing the search and replace.

As both single quotes and double quotes are in the string, a raw string does not help.

Note: This is not direct python, I am doing an ssh into a server through pexpect , and from there executing sed. Here is the python code:

```python
cmd = "sed -i 's/{0}.*/{0}\": \"{1}\",/' {2}/{3}".format("ip","1.1.1.1","/root/","temp.json")
print (cmd) 
'sed -i \'s/pop.*/pop": "1.1.1.100",/\' /root/temp.json'
```

> The Addition backslash before ('s ) is the cause.

Comment: Can you provide the `pexpect` code aswell that sends/expects this?

Comment: cmd = 'sed -i \'s/ip.*/ip": "1.1.1.1",/\' temp.json'

hdl.sendline(cmd)
hdl.expect_exact(["$","#"],30)

Comment: Remember to quote your single quotes i.e `\'` should be `'\''`.

Comment: The string you show is what you get by dumping the variable `cmd` when using python3 interactively in the terminal. `print(cmd)` will show you the real value of the string, and there will be no backslash.  Try `for ch in cmd:do print(ch)` to see each character.

Comment: @meuh : it was print(cmd) output , i will update. backslash is appended.